# .Net Iframe resulting in 404 error

Tags: c#, .net, iframe

I am trying to pull a c# page into an iframe but I keep getting a 404 error! Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code? I believe that it is setup right?

```
<iframe id="FRAME1" runat="server" src="~/requestphonecall.aspx"></iframe>
```

Many thanks!

Comment: A 404 indicates that the file can't be found. Is your path right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '~/' path shortcut can only be used server-side. An iframe is in client-side script so you need a relative or absolute HTTP URL

Comment: _client-side element_, iframe is an element!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<iframe id="FRAME1" runat="server" src="requestphonecall.aspx"></iframe>
```

Error 404 indicate path problem.Without knowing ur application structure its not possible to say whats a problem?